# Replace a FlexLayout with a StackLayout

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I have a `Grid` with two rows in Auto within a `CollectionView`. In one I have a `FlexLayout`, in the other a `Label`. For some strange problem, with these two controls the `Label` is not displayed and the only way I have found so far is to replace the `FlexLayout` with a `StackLayout`.

```
 <DataTemplate>
                         <yummy:PancakeView  CornerRadius="15">
                             <yummy:PancakeView.Shadow>
                                 <yummy:DropShadow Color="LightBlue" Offset="10,10"/>
                             </yummy:PancakeView.Shadow>
                             <Grid BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource SfondoElemDiario}" RowSpacing="0.2">
                                     <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                         <RowDefinition Height="27"/>
                                         <RowDefinition Height="27"/>
                                         <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                         <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                     </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                         <ColumnDefinition Width="65"/>
                                         <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                     <ColumnDefinition Width="32"/>
                                 </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        
                                     <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" Margin="4,4,4,7" Source="{Binding Umore}" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                                     <Label Grid.Row="0" FontFamily="FontM" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding GiornoTrascritto}" FontSize="16" TextColor="{DynamicResource TextColor}" Opacity="0.6" VerticalOptions="Center" />
                                     <Label Grid.Row="1" FontFamily="FontM" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Orario}" FontSize="16" TextColor="{DynamicResource TextColor}" Opacity="0.6" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                                     <ProgressBar Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" ProgressColor="LightGray" HeightRequest="10" Progress="1" VerticalOptions="End"/>
                                     <ProgressBar Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" ProgressColor="{Binding ColoreUmore}" HeightRequest="10" Progress="{Binding ProgValore}"  VerticalOptions="End"/>
                                     <FlexLayout
                                         Grid.Row="2"
                                         Margin="0,5,10,0"
                                         Grid.Column="1"     
                                         BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding IconDiaries}" 
                                         Wrap="Wrap" 
                                         JustifyContent="Start" 
                                         Direction="Row" 
                                         AlignItems="Start" 
                                         AlignContent="Start">
                                         <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                             <DataTemplate>
                                                 <Grid Padding="0,2,3,0">
                                                     <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                         <RowDefinition Height="18"/>
                                                     </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                         <ColumnDefinition Width="18"/>
                                                         <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                                     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                     <controls:TintedImage Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding isSource}" Margin="2" TintColor="{Binding ColoreUmore}"/>
                                                     <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" FontFamily="FontM" Text="{Binding id}" TextColor="{DynamicResource TextColor}" Opacity="0.9" FontSize="13" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,3,0"/>
                                                 </Grid>
                                             </DataTemplate>
                                         </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                     </FlexLayout>
                                     <Label Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" FontFamily="FontM" TextColor="{DynamicResource TextColor}"  FontSize="16" Text="{Binding Nota}"/>
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCvyM.jpg)

Is there any way to turn this `FlexLayout` into a `StackLayout` and be able to visualize in the same way?

Comment: no, you cannot make a StackLayout behave like a FlexLayout.  It appears to me that your Label IS displaying, except when it needs to wrap.  I'd assume this is some problem in calculating the size of the Grid cell.  Have you logged an issue and submitted a test case?

Comment: I entered the complete code. the last Label is not displayed. If you try to take a test you will be able to see it too

Comment: I have no idea what you mean.  Are you talking about the Label after the FlexLayout?  Or the Label inside the FlexLayout?  Your screenshot seems to show 6 icons and 6 pieces of text, so I assume that means that you have 6 elements in your FlexLayout and it is displaying the DataTemplate for each one.

Comment: I mean the final Label, the one after the FlexLayout. It is not shown if I set the Row to Auto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `*` instead of `Auto` for your FlexLayout row.

```
    <Grid BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource SfondoElemDiario}" RowSpacing="0.2">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="27" />
            <RowDefinition Height="27" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <!-- elements -->
    </Grid>
```

Comment: It works!! why inserting * instead of Auto solves the problem?

Comment: Thats [a known issue](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/5265) from XF repo, incorrect calculation from the wrapping content of FlexLayout. And the workaround here is good because only one line needs "*", which is the FlexLayout one.